# Pareto or pareto?

Tags: r, statistics

This is regarding the R package for the Pareto distribution. I have come across two packages so far and both give results in the same range more or less. My question is if there is a difference using either package.

An example code snippet for Pareto:

```
rPareto(n, t, alpha, truncation = NULL)
```

Example code snippet for pareto:

```
rpareto(n, location, shape = 1)
```

Comment: (1) Which two packages? I can find [`Pareto`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Pareto/index.html), which other one are you keeping secret from us? (2) Unless you have concrete (_objective_) criteria, there's a lot of "opinion" with questions like this. Please try to be more concrete in your metrics of worth.

Comment: What determines which class is "better" in your mind? That seems like a very subjective label. Questions about opinions are considered off-topic.

Comment: @r2evans I am new to this and when searching for Pareto in R, found this link: https://rdrr.io/cran/EnvStats/man/Pareto.html. That is where my doubts arose. Is there a difference between the both? Or am I just speaking on no basis?

Comment: @MrFlick My question concerning this post was if there was a difference using either package. It does seem subjective to phrase it as 'better', though.

Comment: That information belongs in the question, please [edit] it (comments can be easily missed by readers or hidden by the Stack interface). However ... it sounds as if you have no objective ways to compare them, you're looking for others' opinions (which is, as MrFlick already said, [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Understandable, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: My thoughts: Do they both have mathematically-correct implementations? Are there corner-cases or error-conditions that one handles better than the other? If you're looking for large-ish draws from the pareto distribution, does one have a performance advantage over the other? Are they both written to allow reproducibility? Are they both sufficiently documented and give you the func-args you need to control the draw? (That last question is somewhat subjective or at least contextual, we don't know your context.) Many questions require a code audit, I suggest you run your own tests first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can test which samples from `rpareto` from `EnvStats` or `rPareto` from `Pareto` give closer approximations to the true Pareto distribution. The true Pareto distribution has cdf 1-(xm/x)^a where xm is scale and a is shape. A Kolmogorov-Smirnov test can be used to compare the samples to this true cdf from either function. Based on the p-value, we can say which sample is 'closer' to the true cdf (with higher p-value being closer). (Of course, this is just one way to go about doing this.)

```
paretocdf = function(x, xm, a) {
  return(1-(xm/x)^a)
}
library(Pareto)
library(EnvStats)
pvalue1 = NULL
pvalue2 = NULL
for (i in 1:1000) {
  X=unique(rPareto(10000, 1000, 2))
  Y=unique(rpareto(10000, 1000, 2))
  pvalue1[i] = ks.test(X, paretocdf, 1000, 2)$p.value
  pvalue2[i] = ks.test(Y, paretocdf, 1000, 2)$p.value
}
mean(pvalue1 > pvalue2)
```

According to my analysis, both functions are approximately the same.